# MySQL, How do I only select rows based on other rows data?

Tags: mysql

Ok, here's the deal, I have a table for stats where there are different types and I only want to select a row if it has a previous (not directly previous) row that has some matching data (hash) and is unique based on another column value.

In the following example we need to only get SALE rows

This example should help:

```
id    link_id   member_id   stat_type   hash
----------------------------------------------
108   41        82          SALE        fffff
107   41        82          CLICK       fffff
106   41        82          CLICK       eeeee
105   41        67          SALE        ddddd
104   41        67          CLICK       ddddd
103   41        35          SALE        ccccc
102   41        35          CLICK       bbbbb
101   41        35          CLICK       aaaaa
```

The only row I want to get back here is member_id = 67 because that member's only previous CLICK to link_id 41 has the same hash. Members 82 and 35 do not get selected because they both have a previous click to link_id 41 with a mismatched hash.

Query result should be:

```
id    link_id   member_id   stat_type   hash
----------------------------------------------
105   41        67          SALE        ddddd
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, then you first need to group the table by `link_id` and `member_id`, filter those groups for ones that contain only one distinct `hash`, and then join the results back to your table to obtain all the matching `SALE` records:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   link_id, member_id
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY link_id, member_id
  HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT hash) = 1
) t WHERE stat_type = 'SALE'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8123dd/1/0).

Comment: Not sure if there's a faster way to query the data or not, but this works. The only reason for faster would be because there's 2 million records and growing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this result is to use an anti-join pattern.

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM mytable r
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT t.member_id
              , t.link_id
              , t.hash
           FROM mytable t
          GROUP
             BY t.member_id
              , t.link_id
              , t.hash
       ) s
    ON s.member_id = r.member_id
   AND s.link_id   = r.link_id
   AND NOT (s.hash = r.hash)
 WHERE r.stat_type = 'SALE'
   AND s.member_id IS NULL
```

The inline view (derived table) aliased as `s` gets all of the distinct hash values for each member_id and link_id. That is left joined to all of the rows in the table that have `stat_type='SALE'`, with matching member_id and link_id, and with a NON-matching hash.

The "trick" is the `s.member_id IS NULL` predicate. Any rows that found a match (i.e. a non-matching HASH will have a non-null value for s.member_id. Only rows that did not have a match will return a NULL (due to the LEFT JOIN).